# Can a recursive function change a variable in the original calling of the function?

Tags: java, c++, function, recursion

For example. Let's say I have a function called `recursionFunction`. In this function, I set a variable `userInput` equal to a value entered by the user, and then call the function itself. Will the user input that is entered in the recursion change the variable of the original?

My query comes from my small understanding of scopes and addresses. 
If the function is different then the variable should not be recognised as the same variable. But it is the 'same function', isn't it? It should have the same address in RAM and therefore be overwritten? Or will it not have the same address despite being in the same function with the same variable name?

Ignore the fact that such a function would cause an infinite loop. Let's pretend I have a way of stopping the program. This is not an opinions question, it will obviously only happen like I have described or not. Thank you in advance.

I work in mainly Java and I am trying to learn C++ which is why those tags are included.

EDIT : Mock code (Again, I know an infinite loop would occur, let's pretend it doesn't) Does the recursion change the userInput variable in the original call?

```
int recursionFunction()
{
    int userInput;

    std::cin >> userInput;

    recursionFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provide some basic code snippet to understand it better. It will depend on the fact whether it is reference or value.

Comment: What is the *type* of that variable `userInput `?

Comment: `Same function = Same address in RAM`. You are confusing things here. You are confusing the `symbol table` with the `execution stack`. When functions run they don't run on the same memory (it is run on a stack, precisely the reason for `stack overflow`).

Comment: Recursion in Java works exactly the same way as recursion in C++. If you understand how recursion in Java works, you should also understand how recursion in C++ works. There's nothing earth-shaterring there. It is the same exact concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are actually asking what happens with local variables during the recursive call. The answer is simple - every function invocation gets its own stack frame, i.e. these local variables are completely isolated from each other. This diagram could help: ([source](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/stacks.html))

[image]

It shows the stack after executing this code:

```
function f(int x, int y) {
    int a;
    if ( term_cond ) return ...;
    a = .....;
    return g(a);
}

function g(int z) {
    int p,q;
    p = ...; q = ...;
    return f(p,q);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, unless using pass by reference as call method.

Each function will have it's own scope. Only if you send in and manipulate pointers to memory, it will be the same.

In this example they will never interfer (although this is an infinite loop never exited, which will create a stack overflow in the end...)

```
void RecursionFunction(void)
{
  unsigned int uiVal;
  uiVal = input();
  RecursionFunction();
}
```

Here it is always the same memory area that is changed in each recursion

```
void RecursionFunction(unsigned int* uiVal)
{
  *uiVal = input();
  RecursionFunction(uiVal);
}

void main()
{
  unsigned int uiVal;
  RecursionFunction(&uiVal)
}
```

and by reference (which will also alter the same memory area):

```
void RecursionFunction(unsigned int &uiVal)
{
  uiVal = input();
  RecursionFunction(uiVal);
}

void main()
{
  unsigned int uiVal;
  RecursionFunction(uiVal)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, if you declare the variable `userInput` as being `static`. This means that the variable will not be on the stack, but rather has a fixed place on the heap. So it acts like a global variable, but it will only be accessible from inside the function.

Comment: Useful piece of information thank you, going with another answer but still, good point.